# Как удалить искомую и предыдущие строки с помощью sed?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, sed

Искомую строку удаляю так:

```
sed -i '/example2/d' file.txt
```

Как удалить искомую и две предшествующие?
файл

```
#EXTINF:-1,Футбол 4
#EXTGRP:Спорт
http://example.com/video/video.m3u8

#EXTINF:-1,Футбол 3
#EXTGRP:Спорт
http://example2.com/video/video.m3u8

#EXTINF:-1,Футбол 2
#EXTGRP:Спорт
http://example3.com/video/video.m3u8
```

хочу получить

```
#EXTINF:-1,Футбол 4
#EXTGRP:Спорт
http://example.com/video/video.m3u8

#EXTINF:-1,Футбол 2
#EXTGRP:Спорт
http://example3.com/video/video.m3u8
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/24979429/1016033

Answer (score 0):

Используйте такую команду:

```
sed -i -r -e '/^$/{N ; N ; N ; N ; s/.*example2.*//;}' file.txt
```

Comment: Опишите пожалуйста логику, как это работает. Хочу понять принцип работы, а не просто копипастить. Спасибо.

Comment: Если убрать пустые строки перед #EXTINF: , то не работает.

Comment: это работает так. Как только будет найдена пустая строка (/^$/) читаем 4 другие (N) строки и если в них есть example2, то все заменяем (s) на пустую строку. Подробности о мультилайновых командах можно прочесть здесь https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Multiline-techniques.html

Comment: в вашем исходном файле каждый блок начинается с пустой строки, поэтому я написал такую команду. Если пустых строк не будет, то /^$/ замените на /^#/ и уберите одну команду N